# How to start a Scala method from command line?

Tags: scala, console

This question may sound a bit stupid, but I couldn't figure out, how to start a Scala method from the command line.

I compiled the following file `Test.scala` :

```
package example

object Test {
  def print() {
    println("Hello World")
  }
```

}

with `scalac Test.scala`.

Then, I can run the method `print` with `scala` in two steps:

```
C:\Users\John\Scala\Examples>scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_32).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> example.Test.print
Hello World
```

But what I really like to do is, to run the method directly from the command line with one command like `scala example.Test.print`.

How can I achieve this goal ?

**UPDATE:**
Suggested solution by ArikG does not work for me - What I am missing ?

```
C:\Users\John\Scala\Examples>scala -e 'example.Test.print'
C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\scalacmd1874056752498579477.scala:1: error: u
nclosed character literal
'example.Test.print'
         ^
one error found

C:\Users\John\Scala\Examples>scala -e "example.Test.print"
C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\scalacmd1889443681948722298.scala:1: error: o
bject Test in package example cannot be accessed in package example
example.Test.print
        ^
one error found
```

where

```
C:\Users\John\Scala\Examples>dir example
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4C49-8C7F 

 Directory of C:\Users\John\Scala\Examples\example

14.08.2012  12:14    <DIR>          .
14.08.2012  12:14    <DIR>          ..
14.08.2012  12:14               493 Test$.class
14.08.2012  12:14               530 Test.class
               2 File(s)          1.023 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  107.935.760.384 bytes free
```

**UPDATE 2 - Possible SOLUTIONs:**

- As ArikG correctly suggested, with `scala -e "import example.Test._; print"` works well with Windows 7.
- See answer of Daniel to get it work without the import statement

Comment: `scala -e ...` works fine on my Mac. Hmm... What about `scala -e "import example._; example.Test.print"`?

Comment: @ArikG You got it. That worked well with my Windows 7 Setup. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me expand on this solution a bit:

```
scala -e 'example.Test.print'
```

Instead, try:

```
scala -cp path-to-the-target-directory -e 'example.Test.print'
```

Where the target directory is the directory where scala used as destination for whatever it compiled. In your example, **it is not** `C:\Users\John\Scala\Examples\example`, but `C:\Users\John\Scala\Examples`. The directory `example` is where Scala will look for classes belonging to the *package* `example`.

This is why things did not work: it expected to find the package `example` under a directory example, but there were no such directory under the current directory in which you ran `scala`, and the classfiles that were present on the current directory were expected to be on the default package.

Comment: Thank you very much. You solution worked - that's great. But it surprises me a bit. I triggered `scala -e "example.Test.print"` under the directory `C:\User\John\Scala\Examples`, so Scala should find the underlyring directory `èxample` which matches with the package. What do I get wrong?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood It should only find it if the current directory is in the "default" classpath. Try `bash -x scala -e "example.Test.print"` to see if it passes any classpath to java. If it doesn't, then there's no default classpath.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this is to extend [App](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/App.html) which is a slightly special class (or at least DelayedInit which underlies it is):

```
package example

object Test extends App {
  println("Hello World")      
}
```

It's still possible to add methods to this as well, the body of the object is executed on startup.

Comment: Thank you. After compiling, I can run this with `scala example.Test`. The drawback from this solution is, that I have to wrap up the methods I want to use in an separate class which extends `App`. But still, it is a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
scala -e 'example.Test.print'
```