# Trouble running Scala file

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/brendon-boldt/improved-halstead) Github project. It says that one should run the line `scala -cp $CLASSPATH:cgrammar.jar runtime.Main [filename]` in order for the application to run.

However, where I run this line with a valid filename, the prompt says "No such file or class on classpath: 'runtime.Main'".

Following the idea of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11957655/2699664) answer, I tried to run the file with `scala -cp $CLASSPATH:cgrammar.jar -e runtime.Main [filename]`, but now it says that `Main` is not a member of package `runtime.Main`.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? I don't know if it matters or not, but I'm using Windows.

Comment: The Jar file doesn't contain the Scala files, i.e. not the `main.scala`. You have to compile the project first. It's similar like for Java, but using `scalac` instead of `javac`

Comment: There is also a Makefile in the project, why not using this?

Comment: I don't usually work with scala projects, and averytime I did, I used an IDE. I'm gonna try and see how is a scala project compiled. It should be just using `scalac` and the name of the files, right?

Comment: Using `make makefile` the prompt says "Nothing to be done for 'makefiel-dir'".

Comment: Well, I think I managed to compile the project by doing `scalac -classpath cgrammar.jar;antlr-runtime-4.0.jar main.scala parser.scala`. Two folders were created: parser and runtime. But now, when I try to run, the prompt still says "no such file or class on classpath: runtime.Main". Any thoguhts on where the problem could be?

Comment: I forked it and added a more Scala project structure to it: https://github.com/whiplash/improved-halstead